# Include VC++ 2015 runtime (x86) + (x64) in One-Click install application

Tags: visual-studio, dll, runtime, prerequisites, oneclick

### Issue

---

I have developed my application in Visual Studio 2015 but when I use the One-Click install and install the application on my clients machine. It needs to have the  `VC++ 2015 runtime (x86) + (x64)` installed.

I have tried looking in the prerequisites but the files do not seem to be in there for me to add.

Is there a way for me to somehow tag on `VC++ 2015 runtime (x86) + (x64)` to my application so when the client installs it, it will also install the runtime.

Comment: It is there, labeled "Visual C++ "14" Runtime libraries.  Three flavors of them.  If you don't see them then your VS edition probably isn't good enough, do avoid developing with the freeware stuff.

Answer (score 1):

There are three ways to do this:

1. build your app with MT instead of MD
2. include the vc_redist package in your package, in the after-install section execute the vc_redist package
3. find a newer packager which support vc2015

[vc_redist_2015](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 1. What is MT and MD? 2. How do do i do this? Sorry, I don't understand how to do these.